# How to calculate force / torque between permanent magnets

Tags: magnets, forces

Given two permanent magnets (for instance, made with ferrite or neodymium with shape of: cylinder, disc, toroid, etc), how can I calculate the force / torque between those magnets? Are there any software (simulator, library) to model it? What books should I get to start in this field?

Comment: perhaps you can start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet#Calculating_the_magnetic_force) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_between_magnets)

Comment: Thanks. In a physics lab school book, even a child can calculate the gravitational force, given mass and gravity constant. For permanent magnets, I was looking for something as simple as that. Given two n42 neodymium magnets, what parameters should I use to calculate the force / torque, with some examples (usually solved questions, in those books).

Comment: From what i understand, each magnet has a 'moment' associated with it. It varies greatly from magnet to magnet and is not as easy to measure as mass (which can be done via a balance). The shape of the magnet also matters I think. Bar magnets might be the easiest. **Even for gravitational force, (high school) text books usually restrict themselves to point masses or spherical masses**. Equivalent situation for magnets might be bar magnets (for which the links provide the equations you are looking for).

Comment: You can try asking in Physics SE if you don't get an answer here.

Comment: In Physics SE there is a somewhat related question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/329992/what-is-the-formula-for-the-pull-force-of-a-cylindrical-magnet